# Microsoft Translator - Invalid Key

Tags: azure, key, microsoft-translator

We've been using the Microsoft Translator for a while, both with a command line script and an an interactive app on a client desktop.

Over the last week or so, we're gettting invalid key errors.

In the interactive version, it says "Key is invalid. Please visit the Azure Portal to obtain a subscription key".
The scripted version just says "Credentials are invalid".

I've tried two different Azure accounts and regenerated the keys, to no avail.

Within the Azure portal, everything looks ok.

By the way, the Translation tool is the latest version 1.4.2

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer my own question, it seems that we hit the ceiling on our entry-level Translation tier.
The free tier covers up to 2M characters per month, but there's no warning when you hit it; you just get "key is invalid".
When I switched to the first payable tier, it came back to life.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please verify that you are subscribed to the Microsoft Translator Text API and using the Translator Text API subscription key and not the Azure subscription key.
2. And/or, check with your software provider and verify if they have the latest version that works with the Microsoft Translator Text API key from the Azure portal.
   Best regards,
   Gwenda
   Microsoft Translator Team